# Paypal Invoice Paid Webhook

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-sandbox, facebook-webhooks

PS: I am unsure the right place to ask this question

I have recently been working with PayPal invoices in an application. This application generates an invoice which the user then pays. It is then meant to listen to PayPals "Invoicing invoice paid" webhook. I have a application created, assigned it the necessary webhook and set the required URL. This is all done in PayPal Sandbox. No event is ever sent to the URL given, no request, no poll, nothing. Nothing is done at all and in the Webhook Event Logs there are no events visible. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Was a transaction created in the receiving sandbox account? Try subscribing to all the webhook event types.

Comment: @PrestonPHX The transaction was created, and the invoice was marked as paid as indented. What would subsricing to all webhook types achieve?

Comment: Log the results and see. Make sure the webhooks are registered for the same application that is sending the invoices.

Comment: @PrestonPHX What do you mean? The application simply generates the invoice using the developer API and sends the user the link generated

Comment: I mean (a) use the same application for subscribing to webhooks as for creating the invoice, and (b) subscribe to all webhooks and log everything that is received after an invoice is paid.

Comment: @PrestonPHX Interesting, when enabling all webhooks it works perfectly however when selecting an individual webhook it fails.

Comment: Interesting, it seems that the simple fact that I was paying with the same account that created the invoice caused it not to send any webhooks.